# How to merge 4 columns based on user-defined criterion

Tags: python

I need to merge 4 columns of an array into a single column

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       ..., 
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

The result should be:

```
array([3, 0, ..., 1])
```

In particular, I want to get column indices (starting from 0 and ending with 3) for those columns that have a value 1.

Comment: @roganjosh: Take a look at the first row `[0, 0, 0, 1]`. The column 3 (if counting starts from 0) has a value 1.

Comment: If you have multiple 1's in one row?

Comment: All sublists contain only '1' and '0', and '1' only appears once in each sublist?

Comment: @JuniorCompressor: I never have multiple 1's in a row.

Comment: The answer by @JuniorCompressor is the one that is appropriate for numpy. Whilst asking for clarification I somehow lost the connection with numpy and gave something appropriate for lists. I will leave my answer as the question does not specify numpy so it might be helpful for others should they land here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every row has a unique one then the following will work:

```
 np.where(a == 1)[1]
```

For example:

```
>>> a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]])
>>> np.where(a == 1)[1]
array([3, 0, 1])
```

We can see it from the following:

```
>>> np.where(a == 1)
(array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 0, 1]))
```

`array([0, 1, 2])` are the row indexes having one values, and `array([3, 0, 1]` are the column indexes. This means that we have one values at coordinates `(0, 3), (1, 0), (2, 1)`. Because each row will have one unique value of one, then there will be one column index for each row.

Answer (score 1):

Based on each row containing only one '1' value, and only with zeros and ones.

EDIT: For some reason I lost the connection with numpy while trying to clarify question. This will not work if using numpy, but I'll leave it in case you were looking for something with just lists.

```
a = [[0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0]]

# One way
single_list = []
for x in a:
    single_list.append(x.index(1))

# or        
using_list_comprehension = [x.index(1) for x in a]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: However, `type(test_fold_y)` gives numpy.ndarray

Comment: I made the edit just before you made this comment, my bad :(